# When to use calling conventions

Tags: visual-c++, calling-convention

What are the key factors on using different calling conventions? When does someone know to use specific calling conventions such as `__cdecl` or `__stdcall` or `__fastcall` in different occasions.

Examples would be really apprciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most of the time you don't need to worry about it. Usually you'll use `__cdecl`, but only because that's the default in Visual C++. C++ member functions, however, use the `__thiscall` convention by default in Visual C++

A (rather common) situation where you really have to worry about calling conventions is when you pass callbacks to API functions, like those in the Windows API:

```
// CALLBACK is #define'd as __stdcall 
LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam); 
// ... 
windowClass.lpfnWndProc = &MyWndProc; 
::RegisterClass(&windowClass);
```

Here, we declare `MyWndProc()` as having the `__stdcall` convention (`CALLBACK` is `#define`'d as `__stdcall`). This is needed because the operating system expects that `lpfnWndProc` points to a `WNDPROC`, [which uses the `CALLBACK` convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-wndproc).

Just about every Windows API function that accepts a callback requires the callback functions to use the `__stdcall` convention, and since `__cdecl` is usually the default, you must make this explicit (you would use `CALLBACK` for window procedures).

This is extremely important because stack corruption can occur if the operating system attempts to call a non-`__stdcall` function. Unfortunately enough people get this wrong that [Windows will actually check for calling convention mismatch specifically for window procedures](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043).

While `__stdcall` is required for callback functions passed to WinAPI functions, functions that accept a variable number of arguments must use the `__cdecl` calling convention, because only the caller will know how to properly pop the variable number of arguments off the stack. Since `__cdecl` is usually the default, you don't need to explicitly specify `__cdecl` for functions that accept a variable number of arguments.

I personally haven't found a use for `__fastcall`, although I'm sure someone has.

`__clrcall` is relevant only if you're interacting with managed code.