# Function calling conventions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, calling-convention

I read a little bit about

```
__crlcall, __stdcall, __fastcall, __vectorcall and __thiscall
```

calling conversion. My question is, when is good to use one of them and what are the advantages (or disadvantages) of using them. Should i even use them?

Comment: I hope you checked it at the msdn. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use calling conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405022/when-to-use-calling-conventions)

Comment: What's actually unclear from [MSVC Calling Conventions reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx) for you? Please elaborate. To be concise: Avoid these for portable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) are commonly used to have a function call adhere to an [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).

An example with a different architecture (a gpu): when calling low-level [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) routines (device functions) you have to adhere to their specific ABI, for instance you need to ensure that every load greater than 1 byte is performed on an address aligned to the multiple of the access size (i.e. if you need to access a 4-bytes integer, that address needs to be 4-bytes aligned).

You can't specify in C++ how registers are allocated / laid out and other low-level details (or perhaps you could but it would be a pain to tweak your code with compiler-specific extensions): that's where the compiler calling conventions come into play.

Regarding when and if you should use them: if you don't know what you're doing, you'd better not use them at all. Mismatching a calling convention on a x86 architecture like  [__stdcall and __cdecl](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/08/48616.aspx) could work anyway (just how things are passed during the function call is different, e.g. stack frames) but in general if you use a wrong calling convention if you're lucky you might just lose some performances (and render your code less portable).. if you're unlucky: **CRASH**! Depending on the architecture the latter can become more and more likely.

**TL;DR:** Use them when you need them. Especially when dealing with low-level details from C or C++ code. Don't ever use them just to "make your code prettier".